# in Spring source code ,a method two variables Generic type was different

Tags: java, spring

[spring-projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java#L150-L152) in this method, why the`priorityOrderedPostProcessors` list stored `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` type ,and `orderedPostProcessorNames`,`nonOrderedPostProcessorNames` stored String. What is the reason for this?  I tried to replace them with the same type and they seem to work fine too.

Comment: Replaced which with what types? I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code from lines 150–189, I don’t see any reason why there's a two-step process for `orderedPostProcessors` and `nonOrderedPostProcessors` but not for `priorityOrderedPostProcessors`. This is the case in the earliest commit of the file in github, so any reasoning behind it is lost in the mists of time. I'd guess that the two cases were added by different developers with different styles. Interestingly, the instantiations of `ArrayList<BeanFactoryPostProcessor>` for `orderedPostProcessors` and `nonOrderedPostProcessors` were updated at a later time to add the small optimization of declaring the size immediately based on the sizes of `orderedPostProcessorNames` and `nonOrderedPostProcessorNames` but that developer apparently never questioned the need for the two-step process.